# SwinjectStoryboard - Is it possible to load / inject a storyboard that its ViewController exists within a different framework in another project?

Tags: swift, xcode, dependency-injection, storyboard, swinject

SwinjectStoryboard - Is it possible to load / inject a storyboard that its ViewController exists within a different framework in another project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is doable just change the storyboard module to point to the framework module.